# Magento 2.2: Order, Invoice, and Shipment do not display in admin grid

Tags: magento2.2, invoice, order-grid, shipment

I added a product to the cart and create order. It displays properly on the front side in **"My Order" tab**.

But, when I checked in admin side order grid, then records not updated in order grid.

I have also do reindexing and flush cache and also async indexing is disabled. But, there is no any luck working.

> Note: When I create invoice or shipment of the previous order, then it's also not created in admin side. But, it's recorded in the database table is already available. Only not display in order grid.

```
admin/sales/order/view/order_id/`<previous_order_id>`/key
```

If direct change by **order_id**, then it'll display. But, record not display in order grid.

The same issue occurred in invoice and shipment.

How to solve it?

Please help me.

Comment: have you run command => php bin/magento indexer:reindex?

Comment: I have already done reindex, cache flush. Asynchronous indexing is disabled.
The issue is I get stuck in the database when I checked the record of last order in sales_order table its record is present. but when I check sales_order_grid table last order's record is not added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue in **increment_id**. So, try to execute this query in your db.

> Note : Here, 7 is current store id which receive order data & 1 is default store id .

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_order_7 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_7 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_shipment_7 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_creditmemo_7 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_rma_item_7 AUTO_INCREMENT = 700001602;

ALTER TABLE sequence_order_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_shipment_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001602;
ALTER TABLE sequence_rma_item_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001602;
```

So, If you execute this query in your db, then you'll get all new upcoming records will be in order grid.

I think it may be helpful to you.